# Rolling regression with dplyr and lsfit

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, zoo

I'm trying to run a rolling regression with `dplyr`. I'm using `rollapplyr` from package `zoo` and `lsfit` as I'm only interested in the beta of the regression. Here's what I've tried:

```
library(dplyr); library(zoo)

df1 = expand.grid(site = seq(10),
                    year = 2000:2004,
                    day = 1:50)

df1 %>%
group_by(year) %>%
mutate(beta1 = rollapplyr(data = site,
                            width = 5,
                            FUN = lsfit,
                            x=day))
```

I'm getting this error: `Error: not all arguments have the same length`

I think `rollapplyr` accepts non-zoo objects but I may be wrong. It could also be that the piping (`%>%`) does not play well with `rollapplyr` as it requires a data object in the function.

Any idea?

**EDIT** My question is different from: [rolling regression with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770478/rolling-regression-with-dplyr) I want to use pipes in order to use `group_by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function will not cycle through multiple vectors. The sliced `site` vector is being compared to the *full* vector `day`. We can write our own rolling apply function with `Map` to go through groups of our vector:

```
rollapplydf <- function(xx, width) {
  l <- length(xx)
  sq <- Map(':', 1:(l-width+1), width:l)
  lst <- lapply(sq, function(i) lm(xx[i] ~ seq(length(xx[i])))$coeff[2] )
  do.call('rbind', c(rep(NA, width-1L), lst))
}
```

So we can add this to the pipe:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(beta1 = rollapplydf(xx = site, width = 5) )

# Source: local data frame [2,500 x 4]
# Groups: year [5]
# 
#     site  year   day beta1
#    (int) (int) (int) (dbl)
# 1      1  2000     1    NA
# 2      2  2000     1    NA
# 3      3  2000     1    NA
# 4      4  2000     1    NA
# 5      5  2000     1     1
# 6      6  2000     1     1
# 7      7  2000     1     1
# 8      8  2000     1     1
# 9      9  2000     1     1
# 10    10  2000     1     1
# ..   ...   ...   ...   ...
```